# on windows, how to execute go bin commands of go cobra package?

Tags: go, go-cobra

I am studying [go cobra](https://cobra.dev/)

I need to execute, on windows, the equivalent of

```
~/go/bin/cobra init
```

I already did

```
 go get -u github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra
```

I don't know how to execute the bin/cobra command because I don't know where it's installed now the cobra package

In my laptop I've this folder

```
C:\Users\mirko\go\bin
```

But there is no cobra command. What I am supposed to do on Windows when starting a project from scratch with cobra?

Comment: `go get` does not install binaries, it updates dependencies. There is also no main package at `github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra` in the current version of cobra, are you sure that is what you're want to install?

Comment: I am followng a book of february 2023, and a few tutorials; no 2 of them telling same things; also the project home page is not mentioning bin/cobra at all. I am lost, that is way I am here asking

Comment: Anything that mentions using `go get` to install binaries is a few years out of date. I would start with the README in the repo: https://github.com/spf13/cobra/

Comment: @JimB thanks. I aded an aswer with credits to you. Also, I created a long errata/corrige for the book I am reading. I hope to be usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comment of @JimB I followd the project readme [here](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/)

First, init a module

```
go mod init <package name>
```

I installed the cobra dep as

```
go get -u github.com/spf13/cobra@latest
```

Then I installed as is the cobra cli

```
go install github.com/spf13/cobra-cli@latest
```

Another usefull REAMDE is [here, about cobra-cli](https://github.com/spf13/cobra-cli/blob/main/README.md)

I can init the cobra project structure using

```
cobra-cli init
```

And the I can create commands like ..

```
cobra-cli add list
cobra-cli add delete 
...
```